# Requires regex for US Phone Format

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, regex

I need a regex that will match the US phone in a slightly different manner. Actually, on my page i have textbox for taking input, there i had place regular expression validator and the regex to validate the zip code in `999-999-9999`. Till here everything was fine. Later on we added MaskedEditor extender to avoid manually adding - in between the codes of phone number. Also the ClearMaskOnLostFocus is set to false. So every time we have `___-___-____` in our textbox. And my validator is now always validating its against invalid input.

**So finally i would like say, i need a regex that will match if my phone is a valid US phone and also passes `___-___-____` , instead of the two it will break..**

**[Existing Regex]**

```
^[0-9]{3}[\-]{1}[0-9]{3}[\-]{1}[0-9]{4}$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
(<your current regex>)|(___-___-____)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript - here:

```
  /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
```

It came from google...
http://www.zparacha.com/phone_number_regex/

Here it is part by part:

```
/^      = match must start with - no chars before
\(?     = optional left brace
(\d{3}) = 3 digits
\)?     = optional right brace
[- ]?   = optional hyphen or space
(\d{3}) = 3 digits
[- ]?   = optional hyphen or space
(\d{4}) = 4 digits
$/      = match must end here - no chars after
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [libphonenumber](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) for inspiration or use. It has most stuff you can need regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

[PhoneFormat.com](http://www.phoneformat.com/) has a javascript library that will take whatever number you throw at it, in whatever format you have, and properly format it.  If you pass `___-___-____` or `999-999-9999` it will handle it just fine.